# Crystal Report -WhilePrintingRecords

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I wrote following formula.

> WhilePrintingRecords; numbervar t=0; t={GLTRAN.CRDIFF}-{GLTRAN.DRDIFF}

when crystal report runtime gives
**Error formula tot
'whilePrintingRecords'
A number is required here
Details:errorKind**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
Numbervar t:=0;
WhilePrintingRecords; 
t:=tonumber({GLTRAN.CRDIFF})-tonumber({GLTRAN.DRDIFF})
```